# Show that $(M, d)$ and $(M, \tau)$ are homeomorphic iff every subset of M is open iff every function $f:(M, d) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space, and let $\tau$ be the discrete metric on $M$.

**Question:** How do I show that the following statements are equivalent:

1) $(M, d)$ and $(M, \tau)$ are homeomorphic

2) every subset of $(M,d)$ is open

3) every function $f:(M, d) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I know that $(M, d)$ and $(M, \tau)$ are homeomorphic if the identity map $i: (M, d) \to (M, \rho)$ and its inverse $i^{-1}: (M, \rho) \to (M, d)$ are both continuous (if d and $\rho$ are equivalent metrics on M).

I have no clue on how I should handle this, Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I'm sorry I must have missed the answers and comments to this question. Regarding the questions; yes, open with respect to the metric.

Comment: In the second of the three equivalent conditions the openness of an arbitrary subset of $M$ is with respect to the metric $d$, right? That needs to be mentioned.

Comment: Is your definition of "continuous" a topological one (i.e. $f:X\to Y$ continuous if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ whenever $U$ is open in $Y$) or is it purely based on metrics?

Comment: HINT: Prove 3 implies 2 implies 1 implies 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a complete answer (I am not informed enough).

Let it be that every function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ is continuous.

Let $m$ be an arbitrary element of $M$ and prescribe function $f:M\to\mathbb R$ by $x\mapsto1$ if $x=m$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

Then $f(m)=1$ and the continuity of $f$ at $m$ tells us that an open set $U$ exists in $M$ with $m\in U$ and $f(U)\subseteq(\frac12,\frac32)$.

This tells us that $U=\{m\}$ so that we can conclude that singleton $\{m\}$ is an open set in $M$.

$m$ was an arbitrary element of $M$, so we conclude that *every* singleton that is a subset of $M$ is an open set in $M$.

Comment: After reading your answer: how could we be sure that $3) \implies 1)$? Is the characteristic function (defined on some subset $U \subseteq M$) continuous for arbitrary metric space $(M,d)$ if it is real-valued?

Comment: @TaylorRendon 3) tells us that every function:$M\to\mathbb R$ is continuous so also the characteristic function of any set $U$. From this it follows that $U$ must be open (because $U$ is the preimage of e.g. the open set $(0,2)$). So we conclude that every subset of $M$ is open. That means exactly that we are dealing with discrete topology on $M$.